# Change CPU count on live Linux VM

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-machine, kvm, hot-plug

Is it possible to change the number of VCPUs on a KVM virtual machine on Linux without stopping it first? The Linux kernel has calls for addition and removal of CPUs ([CPU hotplug in the Kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.0/core-api/cpu_hotplug.html)) for physical machines (on hardware that supports that) but I can't find anything on VMs and how to allocate more/fewer resources to running machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change the VCPU allocation, you do

```
sudo virsh setvcpus [vm_name] [num_vcpus] --current
```

From within the machine, running

```
sudo udevadm monitor -k
```

You'll see a series of messages similar to

```
KERNEL[836.518069] add      /devices/system/cpu/cpu4 (cpu)
KERNEL[836.518095] bind     /devices/system/cpu/cpu4 (cpu)
KERNEL[836.526936] add      /module/intel_rapl_perf (module)
KERNEL[836.534023] remove   /module/intel_rapl_perf (module)
KERNEL[836.561229] add      /module/intel_uncore (module)
KERNEL[836.568971] remove   /module/intel_uncore (module)
KERNEL[836.578821] add      /module/intel_cstate (module)
KERNEL[836.592990] remove   /module/intel_cstate (module)
KERNEL[836.603800] add      /module/intel_rapl (module)
KERNEL[836.604120] add      /devices/virtual/powercap/intel-rapl (powercap)
KERNEL[836.604967] remove   /devices/virtual/powercap/intel-rapl (powercap)
KERNEL[836.613034] remove   /module/intel_rapl (module)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only up to the maximum number of vCPUs in the virtual machine definition. Increasing the maximum number requires a shutdown.

For example, this VM has two vCPUs of a maximum 8. Increasing beyond 8 requires a shutdown.

```
  <vcpu placement='static' current='2'>8</vcpu>
```